# Having trouble converting a unix date to/from Array{UInt8,1} in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to decode binary data that contains UNIX date stamps (time in milliseconds from 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970) and can't understand why I'm unable to accurately convert an Array{UInt8,1} of 8 bytes to (ultimately) a Float64 suitable for converting to a DateTime object.  My input sample is the following array from a variable named `arr`:

```
8-element Array{UInt8,1}:
0x00
0x00
0x01
0x16
0x6a
0xe0
0x68
0x80
```

which represents the datetime value of `2007-11-23T00:00:00`

Then I try to use bit shifting to convert with the following:

```
Float64((Int64(arr[1]) << 56) | (Int64(arr[2]) << 48) | (Int64(arr[3]) << 40) | (Int64(arr[4]) << 32) | (Int64(arr[5]) << 24) | (Int64(arr[6]) << 16) | (Int64(arr[7]) << 8) | Int64(arr[8]))
```

Which gives me `1.195794e12`

dividing by 1000 to get `1.195794e9` which gives me the right size for input to the function Dates.unix2datetime() which gives:

```
julia> Dates.unix2datetime(1.195794e9)
2007-11-23T05:00:00
```

which is close but not exactly what I started with of 2007-11-23T00:00:00 (I'm 5 hours off).

Can anyone shed light on where I have gone astray?  Anyone offer a shorter, simpler way of doing this?  In C one could use a Union to easily convert between an array representation and the target type, but unions in Julia are quite different from C.  (and why do I need to divide by 1000, I would think I could get to the e9 representation directly)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR I think your original unix timestamp was representing the date you found!**

Where did you get the `arr` input array from?

The `arr` you started with does represent `1.195794e12` as can be shown with the slightly more terse:

`parse(Int64,join(bits.(arr)),2)` -> `1.195794e12`

And you do need to divide by 1000 to go from milliseconds to seconds.

```
unix2datetime(x) -> DateTime
Takes the number of seconds since unix epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00 and converts to the corresponding DateTime.
```

But it seems your `arr` represents  as

`Int64(Dates.datetime2unix(DateTime(2007, 11, 23, 0, 0, 0))*1000)` --> `1195776000000`

while `Int64(Dates.datetime2unix(DateTime(2007, 11, 23, 5, 0, 0))*1000)` --> `1195794000000`

Comment: A five hour difference… sounds suspiciously like a timezone offset from the east coast of North America...

Comment: `arr` is my local testing variable that contains the UInt8 array.  I realize that I need to divide by 1000 to go from milliseconds to seconds, but my question is, WHY does the unix2datetime() function require seconds as input and not the natural milliseconds?  The docs for that function state that it takes a UNIX time as input (which ought to mean it takes input as milliseconds).  The five hour difference does indeed suggest that timezone might be causing the difference.  But in that case I would have thought MY interpretation would be -5  hours (not +5 hours)

Comment: See [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  It's the number of seconds since UTC epoch.  And if `arr` was generated by a time-zone aware program, then it would likely display midnight (local time), but store it as 5 am (UTC).